# Host ASP.NET core and ASP.NET (full) in same machine

Tags: iis

I have 2 websites written in ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework 4.5) in same machine using IIS binding port 80 with different host name.

Now I want to host ASP.NET Core into the same machine with another host name but still bind to port 80

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can host it with a different host name the same way as your other MVC application. Make sure you make a new application pool with **no managed code** and install the **.NET core software hosting bundle** on the server.